# how to find tail of a file using c code using 2D array

Tags: c, arrays

I want to print last `n` lines of a file using a **c** program.
I have already used the method of `fseek`. Now, I want to try it by using array. I have written the code, but, it gives a segmentation fault (core dumped) error.

Please help to modify this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char s[10][100];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *in, *out;
    int count = 0;
    long pos;
    char c;

    if ((in = fopen("count.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if ((out = fopen("output.txt", "w")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("error in opening file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (argc < 2)
        fprintf(stderr, "Arguments which is to be passed should be 2\n");
    else if (argc > 2)
        printf("too many argumnets are passed");
    else
    {
        int n = atoi(argv[1]);
        if(n >= 1 &&  n< 100)
        {
            int j,i;
            for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
            {   
                j=0;
                c = fgetc(in);
                for (; j != EOF; ++j)
                {
                    s[i][j]=c;
                    fputc(c, out);
                    c = fgetc(in);
                    if(s[i][j]=='\n')
                        break;
                 }
            if(s[i][j] != EOF && i== n)
               i=0;
         }
         for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
            for (j = 0; s[i][j] != '\n'; j++)
                 printf("%c", s[i][j]);
           }
           else
          printf("renter the value of n");
       }
        fclose(in);
        fclose(out);
        return 0;
     }
```

Comment: How do you explain this part of your code:
`j=0;
                c = fgetc(in);
                while (j != EOF)
                {
                     [...]
                     ++j; [...] }`
How do you expect `j` getting EOF value?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some problems you can look into:

1. `char s[10][100];` See if the sizes match the way you're using `s` : `s[i][j]=c;`
2. `for(i=0;i<=n;i++)` Are you printing n or n+1 lines ?
3. `while (j != EOF)` Inside the loop you're not setting `j` from the file

Plus: the following assignment probably does more harm than good:

```
        if(s[i][j] != EOF && i== n)
           i=0;
```

Comment: Yes I am trying but can't get an exact answer. Will you please help me out by modifying this code

Comment: Have you made fixes in the code ? If you have, can you tell what you did (post the changes in an edit perhaps ?).

Answer (score 0):

While you are free to approach the reading of lines *one-character-at-a-time* using *character-oriented* input functions, you are making your job a bit more difficult than it needs to be. C offers several functions that provide *line-oriented* input (e.g. `fgets` and `getline`), that are much better suited for reading text one *line-at-a-time*.

For your purposes here, it seems you need to read/store all lines of input, then based upon a user given number (say `'n'`), write/display the last `'n'` lines of input to your given output file. While dynamically allocating storage to accommodate an unlimited number of lines or characters does not take that much more effort, below we will use a statically declared array with a `MAXL` maximum number of lines, each containing a `MAXC` maximum number of characters. `MAXL` and `MAXC` will be constants for the code specified using an *anonymous* `enum`. The alternative to using an `enum` is to `#define` both as constants.

Rather than hardcoding filenames and the number of lines to display, you can easily pass that information as arguments to your program, making use of `getopt` to pick off the number of end (or tail) lines to display. Any remaining arguments will be considered input/output filenames (using `stdin` and `stdout` as defaults if no additional filenames are provided as arguments).

Below, two helper functions `xfopen` and `processopts` are used simply to move the error checking for `fopen` and option processing with `getopt` into functions to keep the main body of the code readable.

Using *line-oriented* input greatly simplifies the reading and storing of lines in your `array`. The only twist with *line-oriented* input functions is that they *read-and-include* the trailing `'\n'` (newline) character as part of their input. Meaning your only additional task is to remove the trailing `'\n'` by simply overwriting it with a *nul-terminating* character `'\0'` (or simply `0`). So when reading lines with `fgets`, you will generally see something similar to:

```
while (fgets (array[idx], MAXC, ifp)) /* read each line of input */
{   
    size_t len = strlen (array[idx]); /* get length - used below */

    while (len && (array[idx][len-1] == '\r' || array[idx][len-1] == '\n'))
        array[idx][--len] = 0;  /* strip trailing '\r' & '\n' */

    if (++idx == MAXL) {    /* test if line limit reached */
        fprintf (stderr, "warning: MAXL lines read.\n");
        break;
    }
}
```

Which simply reads a line of information into the buffer `array[idx]`, including a maximum of `MAXC` characters (including the *nul-terminating* character) from the file stream `ifp`.  The length of the string read is found with `strlen` and then working backwards using the length as an index each `'\n'` (or `'\r\n'` on windows) is overwritten with a *nul-terminating* character. Lastly the line index `idx` is incremented and tested against the constant `MAXL` to insure you don't write beyond the end of the array. (if array was dynamically allocated, you would `realloc` here)

That is literally all that is required to do *line-oriented* input. You can efficiently read as many or as few lines as needed simply by calling, or repeatedly calling, `fgets` once per line and then removing the line-endings (there are some addition checks you can do to insure a complete line was read, etc.. not relevant to this discussion - here any part of a line that exceeds `MAXC` chars will simply be read as the next line.)

Putting all the pieces together you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

enum { MAXL = 64, MAXC = 128 }; /* constants for max lines and max chars */

FILE *xfopen (const char *fn, const char *mode); /* helper for fopen */
void processopts (int argc, char **argv, size_t *nlines, FILE **ifp, FILE **ofp);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char array[MAXL][MAXC] = {{0}}; /* array to hold MAXL strings */
    size_t i, idx = 0, nlines = 0;  /* index, num lines to print  */
    FILE *ifp, *ofp;

    processopts (argc, argv, &nlines, &ifp, &ofp);  /* handle option */

    while (fgets (array[idx], MAXC, ifp)) /* read each line of input */
    {   
        size_t len = strlen (array[idx]); /* get length - used below */

        while (len && (array[idx][len-1] == '\r' || array[idx][len-1] == '\n'))
            array[idx][--len] = 0;  /* strip trailing '\r' & '\n' */

        if (++idx == MAXL) {    /* test if line limit reached */
            fprintf (stderr, "warning: MAXL lines read.\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    if (ifp != stdin) fclose (ifp); /* close inputfile */

    if (nlines >= idx) nlines = 0;  /* validate nlines */

    if (nlines) {   /* tail only nlines lines */
        for (i = idx - nlines; i < idx; i++)
            fprintf (ofp, "%s\n", array[i]);
    }
    else {  /* print all lines */
        for (i = 0; i < idx; i++)
            fprintf (ofp, "%s\n", array[i]);    
    }
    if (ofp != stdout) fclose (ofp); /* close output fp  */

    return 0;
}

/* fopen with error checking */
FILE *xfopen (const char *fn, const char *mode)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen (fn, mode);

    if (!fp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "xfopen() error: file open failed '%s'.\n", fn);
        // return NULL;
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return fp;
}

void processopts (int argc, char **argv, size_t *nlines, FILE **ifp, FILE **ofp)
{
    int opt;                        /* used with getopt to parse  */

    /* process '-n X' option to set number of tail lines */
    while ((opt = getopt (argc, argv, "n:")) != -1) {
        switch (opt) {
            case 'n':
                *nlines = atoi (optarg);
                break;
        }
    }
    /* infile/outfile are remaining args (default: stdin/stdout) */
    *ifp = argc > optind ? xfopen (argv[optind], "r") : stdin;
    *ofp = argc > optind + 1 ? xfopen (argv[optind + 1], "w") : stdout;
}
```

**Input File**

```
$ cat dat/captnjack.txt
This is a tale
Of Captain Jack Sparrow
A Pirate So Brave
On the Seven Seas.
```

**Reading/Writing all to stdin/stdout**

```
$ ./bin/fgets_array_static_opt <dat/captnjack.txt
This is a tale
Of Captain Jack Sparrow
A Pirate So Brave
On the Seven Seas.
```

**Tailing last 2 lines to stdout**

```
$ ./bin/fgets_array_static_opt <dat/captnjack.txt -n2
A Pirate So Brave
On the Seven Seas.
```

**Tailing last 3 lines to foo.txt**

```
$ ./bin/fgets_array_static_opt dat/captnjack.txt -n 3 debug/foo.txt
$ cat debug/foo.txt
Of Captain Jack Sparrow
A Pirate So Brave
On the Seven Seas.
```

Let me know if you have any questions.